# Use output of a command to feed another one

Tags: linux, shell, for-loop, awk

I have a command that outputs a list of IP addresses; for example:

```
bash test3.sh
```

Output is:

```
10.4.128.2 10.4.128.3 10.4.128.4 10.4.128.5
```

I want to run a command using these outputs as arguments, like this:

```
fio --client 10.4.128.2 jobfile1 --client 10.4.128.3 jobfile1 --client 10.4.128.4 jobfile1 --client 10.4.128.5 jobfile1
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `printf`:

```
out=$(bash test3.sh)
printf "fio"; printf " --client %s jobfile1" $out; echo
fio --client 10.4.128.2 jobfile1 --client 10.4.128.3 jobfile1 --client 10.4.128.4 jobfile1 --client 10.4.128.5 jobfile1
```

Comment: Great answer - I'd forgotten (or perhaps never knew) that `printf` repeats until its arguments are consumed.  Note for others using this technique: the leading space in the `printf` format string matters: if you begin the format with `-`, you'll need to tell `printf` that its options have ended: `printf -- "--client %s jobfile1 "`.